# I wanted to match only 0-0-0 or 0-0-0-0-0 using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex for exacting matching the either 0-0-0-0 or 0-0-0 in the below contents in the log file
but when i use /0-0-0/ as a regex it also matches three zeroes from 0-0-0-0 which is not needed.
6/16/2021 8:35:00 AM - Message= Message: Hi How are you
0-0-0-0-0
6/16/2021 8:35:00 AM - Message= Message: Hi How are you
0-0-0
6/16/2021 8:35:00 AM - Message= Message: Hi How are you
0-0-0-0

Can anybody suggest a regex to only match if 0-0-0-0-0 or 0-0-0 but not match three zeros from 0-0-0-0

thanks,
Abby

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to match three or five `0`s but not 4? Or any number of `0`s, just no duplicates? The following will work for three or five but not four: `/\b0-0-0(-0-0)?\b/`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to anchor to the start and end of the string causing it to be an exact match

```
/^(0-0-0|0-0-0-0-0)$/
```